# PyQt - Pass Combobox text to a variable

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a combobox drop down which contains a list of customers from a SQL query. I have a different button called FinalButton where I want to perform additional actions. One of those things will require me to get the customer name in the combobox and store it in a variable for use in FinalButton.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from config_assign_ui import Ui_ConfigAssign
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ConfigAssign):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.combo_list()
        self.FinalButton.clicked.connect(self.final_button)


    def combo_list(self):
        self.customerlistbox.clear()
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
            r'SERVER=server;'
            r'DATABASE=db;'
            r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
            )

        querystring = """SELECT CustomerName
                         FROM [CustomerTable]"""

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(querystring)
        customerlist = []
        # Dump results into a list called customerlist
        customerlist = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        for i in customerlist:
            self.customerlistbox.addItem(str(i))

    def final_button(self):
        print(self.customerlistbox.itemText())
```

The last line produces TypeError: itemText(self, int): not enough arguments. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemText()` is a method that returns the text of the item given an index, in your case you are not passing it. I think that what you require is the text of the selected item and for that you must use `currentText()`

```
def final_button(self):
    print(self.customerlistbox.currentText())
```

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc. I tried currentText before, but I must have been doing something wrong (e.g. passing self as an argument after currentText).